# How do I convert a large number of OracleParameter declarations to use OracleDbTypeEx in ODP.Net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, type-conversion, odp.net

I'm dealing with yet another poorly written old VB app that used `System.Data.Client` and worked on .Net 1.1 with older versions of Oracle.  It needs to be updated to use 3.5 and the ODP.Net Oracle library.  The project has been mostly tedious cleanup, like implementing `usings` and similar, but I've hit a wall.

All of the methods and functions we had just casually assumed a .Net datatype in return values.  There was a lot of lazy coding where even parameters weren't checked by `.Value` and somehow everything still worked.  Since the upgrade, these methods no longer work, particularly where the result of a given query no longer returns a .Net datatype.  I've overcome most issues, but one problem could turn into a week of typing for me and I'm trying to find a fix.

We have a lot of `OracleParameter` values going in like this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("aNumber", OracleDbType.Double)
 cmd.Parameters(cmd.Parameters.Count -1).Direction  = ParameterDirection.Output
```

The problem here is that the `OracleDbType` property is set, but not the `OracleDbTypeEx`, which returns a .Net datatype that can be digested by the existing code.  Rather than re-write hundreds of parameter declarations, I've tried the following fix:

```
 clsMisc.Prepare(cmd)
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and in my "clsMisc" class:

```
Public Shared Sub Prepare(ByRef cmd As OracleCommand)
        If (Not cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim oc As New List(Of OracleParameter)
        For Each p As OracleParameter In cmd.Parameters
            If p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput Or p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output Or p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue Then

                Dim param = New OracleParameter() With { _
                    .OracleDbTypeEx = p.OracleDbType,
                    .ParameterName = p.ParameterName,
                    .Direction = p.Direction,
                    .Size = p.Size
                }
                oc.Add(param)                   
            Else
                oc.Add(p)
            End If
        Next
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.BindByName = True
        For Each op As OracleParameter In oc
            cmd.Parameters.Add(op)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, even though this compiles and runs, I get two different results from the query.  Without my fix, I get values but in the wrong datatype.  With my fix, all of the return and output values come back as `Nothing` when they shouldn't.  What am I missing, or will I need to go through all of our code and change the parameter declarations manually?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after I posted this, I found the culprit.  Variable names were being assigned to the parameters before population, made static, and then called again to fetch the values further down the code.  I'll still have to adjust those calls, but it's less work than the entire declaration.